# How to get gif image from a link in android-gif-drawable? [Android]

Tags: android, image, gif

I'm using [this](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable) library to display my gif files. When my gif files are saved in my device storage it displays the `gif` file okay, by using

```
GifDrawable gifFromPath;
File gifFile;


GifImageView gifImageView = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageHome);

gifFile = new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), imageName);
try {
                gifFromPath = new GifDrawable(gifFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
gifImageView.setImageDrawable(gifFromPath);
```

I'm wondering how can I display the `gif` file if instead of using the `path` where it is saved I want to get the `gif` from a `link` / `url`.

Comment: Download the file and then display it.

Comment: @KNeerajLal how ?

Comment: Using `HttpUrlConnection`.

Comment: do I need to save it in my storage? I just want to display it.

Comment: Only if you want to display it again (cache).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-getting-started) library. And I use `ImageView` instead.

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);

Glide.with(this).load(url).into(myImageView);
```